# How to insert a PNG file into SQL Server using Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I need to grab local screen shots and insert them into a varbinary(max) field in sql server. I have tried many different ways and have either inserted data that isn't formatted correctly or I get a 'paramter is not valid' error. Or I get a 'Invalid descriptor index' error.

I am using adodbapi in order to connect to SQL.

Here is what I have so far:

```
with open("path.png", "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    b = bytearray()

query = "insert into table (imageData) values (?)

cursor.execute(query, b)
```

Or I can convert b to a hex string and run a query like this:

```
query = "insert into table 
(imageData) values 
(CONVERT(varbinary(max), '" 
+ str(hex_b) + "'))"
```

The above inserts successfully but is in the wrong format, I get a value in sql like this: 0x383935303465...
And the format I need is:
0x89504E470D0A...

An update to the above: when I check the value of hex_b before inserting, it shows: 0x89504E470D0A but after inserting in the db reads as 0x383935303465. So it must be something with how python and adodbapi are sending that data to SQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, most of what I have found has been for inserting into MySQL where they can use blobs.

Comment: In your second example less `'` characters maybe? `0x89504E470D0A` is a binary literal whereas `'89504E470D0A'` is a string literal. With your first example have you tried [`setinputsizes`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#setinputsizeslist_of_value_tuples) specifying the data type as `pyodbc.SQL_VARBINARY` and a length of `-1`?

Comment: I have not tried that, but I'm having to use adodbapi and not pyodbc. Is there an equivalent in adodbapi?

Comment: adodbapi also has [setinputsizes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#setinputsizes). You'll need to grok their spartan documentation to figure out what parameters it needs.

Comment: Alright so I've been digging around and I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for this. I've tried cursor.setinputsizes(adodbapi.adLongVarBinary) = -1 but I get an error: "can't assign function to call". I can take out the data type inside the setinputsizes and it'll be fine but it doesn't do anything. So it seems like adodbapi has all of the correct pieces but their documentation is so sparse I can't put it all together correctly.